# Can the Origin artifact be unlocked on Drizzle difficulty?

Tags: risk-of-rain

Can the Origin artifact be unlocked on Drizzle difficulty?

Drizzle difficulty would make the run much easier, but I'm afraid that even if I beat the game, the artifact wouldn't be unlocked.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. There are no restrictions on the difficulty for which it can be obtained, unlike characters. You can unlock it in any difficulty.

The only condition you need to fulfill to unlock this artifact is to defeat Providence with all other artifacts active.

Comment: Oh, I have been trying to do it on the second difficulty. This helps a lot.